# Creating nd matrices in Eigen using arrays or vectors

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, eigen, smart-pointers

I’ve encountered a problem when working with Eigen in C++. Eigen doesn’t support n-dimensional matrices (beside the unsupported Tensor class which is actually not an option). What I need is a dynamically allocated rank 4 tensor. Now I’ve two options:

1. Using an `std::vector<std::vector<Eigen::MatrixXd>>>` which seems like an bad idea because every vector will allocate it’s own memory (somewhere) and hence, it will not really be efficient.

   2. Using an dynamically allocated 2d-Array inside a `std::unique_ptr` because I don’t want to manually free the pointer. The downside of this is actually, that one usually shouldn’t use arrays wrapped inside a `std:unique_ptr` nowadays because for dynamically allocated arrays we have `std::vector`.

Could someone give me a hint towards the right direction or suggest another approach?

Comment: I believe the right tool for the job is actually the unsupported Tensor class. It might be unsupported but there is plenty of documentation and mature enough for my own research. In fact I'm surprised it still has the "unsupported" label. Why isn't it an option for you?

Comment: Well, it’s because of the unsupported part of it. I’d like to avoid interface changes with newer versions of Eigen. I’ve read the documentation already and it seems quite good. I also worry a bit about performance since I’m not sure how it turns out because of the unsupported label. What’s your experience with it?

Comment: I have used it since 3.3.2, in 2017. By then the API was working well and remains unchanged today in 3.3.7, at least that I've noticed. In terms of performance I'm happy with it and can't find anything that beats it. Implementing my own would take a lot of time and probably end up being worse. I find the syntax a bit verbose for contractions, and prefer the numpy-way (two index lists, one for each tensor), but that is easily fixed with some helper functions. If the API changes (which I don't see any reason for), perhaps consider locking the release?